# Angular 6 HttpClient doesn't handle HttpHeaders as expected

Tags: angular

I'm upgrading an app from Angular 4 to Angular 6. 
I know I should be using an `Interceptor` but I don't want to make more breaking changes than I already am.

I've been reading a lot about `HttpClient` and `HttpHeaders`. My app uses a service I called `HttpRequester` to add an `Authorization` header when necessary. Now there's something I don't understand.

This code **WORKS** :

```
private addTokenHeader(options: any): any {
    if (!options) {
      options = {};
    }
    if (!options.headers) {
        options.headers = {'Authorization': `Bearer ${this.tokenService.getToken()}`};
    }
    return options;
}

get(resource: string, options?: any): Observable<T> {
    options = this.addTokenHeader(options);
    return this.http.get(`${this.hostUrl}${resource}`, options).
    map((res: any) => res.value);
}
```

**This code, however, doesn't work the way I expect :**

```
private addTokenHeader(options: any): any {
if (!options) {
  options = {};
}
if (!options.headers) {
  options.headers = new HttpHeaders({'Authorization': `Bearer ${this.tokenService.getToken()}`});
return options;
}


get(resource: string, options?: any): Observable<T> {
    options = this.addTokenHeader(options);
    return this.http.get(`${this.hostUrl}${resource}`, options).
    map((res: any) => res.value);
}
```

The main difference here is I'm trying to use the `HttpHeaders`
 object as shown [here](https://angular.io/guide/http#adding-headers)

The result is that the headers are not sent and are shown as `[object Map]`
 when debugging the request.

Here's a screenshot of the non-working way :

[image: the debugger shows this when using the second method]

I'm not stuck with that bug, I can still use the first way and it works well for my case. Still I **NEED** to understand what's going on here and what I'm missing. Any help, comment or suggestion is welcome! Thanks!

My setup :

**Browser** : Chrome 67

**OS** : Mac OS 10.13.5

**`ng version` output** :

```
Angular CLI: 6.0.8
Node: 10.7.0
OS: darwin x64
Angular: 6.0.9
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... platform-server, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.6.8
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.6.8
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.6.8
@angular-devkit/core              0.6.8
@angular-devkit/schematics        0.6.8
@angular/cdk                      6.4.0
@angular/cli                      6.0.8
@angular/flex-layout              6.0.0-beta.16
@angular/material                 6.4.0
@ngtools/webpack                  6.0.8
@schematics/angular               0.6.8
@schematics/update                0.6.8
rxjs                              6.2.2
typescript                        2.7.2
webpack                           4.8.3
```

Comment: Can you show the output of `console.log(options)`  just  before passing it to the get method? And dumb question  but can you confirm that the `http` member is indeed an instance of `HttpClient`

Comment: @David somehow you put me on the solution. I'll write an answer about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @David's comment I was able to find out what the problem was.

My imports were good ( `import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';` )
And the `http` attribute was indeed an instance of `HttpClient`.

But I still had references to the old package `@angular/http` and its `HttpModule` was still injected in my main `AppModule`.

This was causing the `HttpClient` to behave in a weird way.

After removing every remaining reference to `@angular/http` in my project I was able to make it work the way it is documented.

Upgrading an existing codebase is not an easy task